# Allow several styles of indentation with Checkstyle

Tags: checkstyle

I'm using checkstyle to analyse Java code readability. The modules I'm using are LineLength, NoLineWrap, NeedBraces, LeftCurly, RightCurly, WhitespaceAround, OneStatementPerLine, EmptyLineSeparator, SeparatorWrap, GenericWhitespace, Indentation and CommentsIndentation. If you know any more modules that might be related to code readability please let me know.

**My problem is:** I'm not really interested in knowing if the code analysed follows some code standard (Google, Sun, etc) I just want to know if the code is readable in a general way. Right now I'm having issues in the modules **LeftCurly** and **Indentation**.

In the case of LeftCurly I want to be able to accept both EOL and NL because I think both styles are readable.

In the case of indentation I don't want to define a tabsize, or the question tabs vs spaces, I just want consistency. I think I could achieve this by allowing several tabsizes but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!